# Filter loop Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel, automation

I am trying to use the AutoFilter and getting the criteria using a values from a different sheet, however its only getting the count value of the last record in the loop.

```
For iLoop = 1 To 10

    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(iLoop, 1).Value

    Dim LR As Long
    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A2:AD" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AD$146").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=RGB(255, _
        0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor

    cCnt = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(5).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
        .Cells.Count - 1

    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B2:B11").Value = cCnt

Next iLoop
```

Comment: what do you mean "get"?  Where is it "getting" it?  is the problem that `cCnt` only includes the final loop's count?  Perhaps that `Range("B2:B11").Value = cCnt` is assigning the one value to 10 cells each time?

Comment: cCnt is returning the count of the last count of visible cells from the loop . not each one  from the filter.

Comment: Did you try the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49191531/8112776)?

Comment: Yes Ashlee , sorry for being late, it works perfectly as desired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that this:

```
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B2:B11").Value = cCnt
```

assigns the (only) value stored in `cCnt` to the same range over and over.  So it's getting (possibly) different values in each iteration of the loop, but you're only seeing the last one.

Perhaps what you intended to do is something like:

```
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B" & iloop + 1).Value = cCnt
```

So, in the first iteration of the loop (when `iLoop=1`), it will assign the value in `cCnt` to Cell `B2`.  When `iLoop=2`, it will assign `cCnt` to `B3`, etc...

---

### More Information:

- [VBA For Loop – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-for-loop/)